# I tried to write Add function in mips but i got wrong answer

Tags: mips

I wrote an add function in MIPS :

```
.data

str:       .asciiz  "\n"

.text

.globl main

main:

    li $s0, 18

    addi $sp, $sp, -4

    sw $s0, 0($sp)

    li $v0, 1

    la $a0, add

    syscall



    li $v0, 4

    la $a0, str

    syscall


    addi $sp, $sp, 4

    jr $ra

add:

    lw $t0, 0($sp)

        add $v0, $t0, $t0

        jr $ra
```

when i try to simulate it i got wrong answer like 4194388. Did i make something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to call your add routine using a syscall.

The proper way to call your routine would be `jal add`